# Connection via SSH works once or twice then never again for that client

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, firewall

I have recently set up a Ubuntu Server minimized. I initially used the server through an SSH with client1 but after one use I kept getting Connection Timed Out when attempting to ssh from client1. I used another client, client2, and it worked perfectly. I then used client2 the next day and I got the same issue. These connections are all via my LAN setup and are not public facing. If I port forward 22 on my router and ssh via the WAN it works every time so far. I do not want to open ssh to the WAN for security reasons. In the ufw.log it says `[UFW BLOCK]` with my router's IP as the source but nothing useful other than that. If I run ssh with the -vvv flag I get `async io completed with error: 10060` before it says it timed out. Iptables has nothing useful either. I uninstalled and reinstalled iptables, ufw, and OpenSSH and it did not fix the problem. I have another Ubuntu Server running on the same LAN and have never experienced this with that server. Maybe it is because that server is connected over ethernet and the one with the issue is over wifi? It is worth noting that if I VPN into the LAN I can connect with the server from a previously 'blocked' client using the assigned IP. It could be worth noting that both of my clients are Windows machines, but they have no issues with the other Ubuntu Server. If anyone has any clue as to what could be causing this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please use `ssh` with the `-vv` flag to get actual error messages. Then add these to your question.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting banned by *fail2ban* or something similiar running on the server.

Comment: i tried ssh with the -vvv flag and it gave me “async io completed with error: 10060”. I would have thought it was being blocked by fail2ban or similar but i haven’t installed anything like that on it.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://hstechdocs.helpsystems.com/manuals/globalscape/archive/cuteftp6/socket_errors_10060,_10061,_10064,_10065.htm